# Return value of Cake\Database\TypeFactory::build() must implement interface Cake\Database\TypeInterface, instance of App\Database\Type\CryptedType

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

After upgrading to cakephp 4 I have this error when I try to do any query:

Return value of Cake\Database\TypeFactory::build() must implement interface Cake\Database\TypeInterface, instance of App\Database\Type\CryptedType returned

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that your custom database type class `\App\Database\Type\CryptedType` does not implement the required interface `\Cake\Database\TypeInterface`.

As of CakePHP 4.0, database type classes should not extend `\Cake\Database\Type` anymore, it is deprecated and will be removed completely in 5.x. For now the `\Cake\Database\Type` is an alias for `\Cake\Database\TypeFactory`, which does *not* implement the interface.

Your custom type classes should now either extend `\Cake\Database\Type\BaseType`, or directly implement the interface.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Adding Custom Types](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types)**

Answer (score 0):

Check your boostrap.php may be using the old type in there after upgrade

```
Type::build('time');
Type::build('timestamp');

Cake\I18n\Date::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');


Type::build('date')
    ->useLocaleParser()
    ->setLocaleFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');

Type::build('datetime')
    ->useLocaleParser()
    ->setLocaleFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing cache

```
bin/cake cache clear_all
```